# matlab jacobi iteration method, giving me matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

below is my code to perform jacobi iterations to solve Ax=b. 
I try this code on the matrix `A =[4 -1 1; 4 -8 1; -2 1 5]` and `b=[7 -21 15]`.
and x is a first guess 1 x 3 vector. Are not these dimensions correct? It gives me the error in the code that calculates: `r = b - x*A`
and `M\(x*N + b)`

What am I missing?!? how do I fix this? please help!

```
function [x, error, iter, flag] = jacobi(A, x, b, maxiter, tol)

%implement jacobi iterations
%[x, error, iter, flag] = jacobi(A, x, b, maxiter, tol)
%jacobi.m solves the linear system Ax=b using the Jacobi iteration
%
%
%INPUT A       the matrix of the system Ax=b
%      x       the first guess vector Ax=b
%      b       the vector in the system
%      maxiter the maximum number of iteration to perform
%      tol     the tolerance
%
%OUTPUT x      the solution vector
%       error  error norm
%       niter  the number of iterations it took
%       flag   indicates whether a solution was found. 0 means there was a
%              solution and 1 means there was not a solution
iter = 0;
flag = 0;

bnrm2 = norm(b);
if (bnrm2 == 0)
     bnrm2 = 1.0; 
end

r = b - x*A;
error = norm(r) / bnrm2;
if (error<tol) 
    return; 
end

[m,n] = size(A);

M = diag(diag(A));
N = diag(diag(A)) - A;

for iter = 1:maxiter,
    oldx = x;
    x = M\(x*N + b);

    error = norm(x - oldx) / norm(x);
    if (error <= tol)
        break;
    end
end
if (error > tol) 
     flag = 1; 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, in the code, you're solving what I'll call (not sure if it's proper since I never do it) the left-multiply problem, the operator and order of matrices are, in some sense, reversed.

If you were solving the problem `A*x = b` with the residual `r = b - A*x` (i.e., `x` and `b` are column vectors), you would perform right-vector multiplies and left-matrix divides.  Therefore, the update line in the loop would be

```
x = M \ (N*x + b);
```

Conversely, if you were solving the problem `x*A = b` with the residual `r = b - x*A` (i.e., `x` and `b` are row vectors), you would perform left-vector multiplies and right-matrix divides.  Therefore, the update line in the loop would be

```
x = (x*N + b) / M;
```

Note that `\` resolves to the function [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) and `/` resolves to [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html).  There is no function distinction for the multiply.

It appears your current updater mixes the two, which is bad news bears for dimension matching.